# Program doesn't output text to console

Tags: c

I'm using an UNIX online terminal to write this code. The program compliles successfully but it won't output anything to the console. It seems to ignore printf() and putchar instructions

```
if(pid > 0) 
{
    file = open("comenzi.txt", O_WRONLY);
    read(file, ch, sizeof(ch));
    printf("%s", ch);
    write(fd[1], ch, sizeof(ch));
    close(fd[1]);
    close(file);
}
else { //procesul fiu
    while(read(fd[0], &rd, 1) > 0);
    putchar(rd);
    close(fd[0]);
}
```

How do I make it output text to console? Thanks.

Comment: print pid before `if` to find out its value

Comment: Why are you reading from a file descriptor that was opened in write-only mode?

Comment: Please always include a full-enough example that we can try to compile it as well, but this has a lot of issues.  For one, the file is opened for writing only but you're attempting to read from it, the code does not check for the proper return from `read()` (which is probably failing), and without seeing the type of `ch` it's hard to tell if this is being done correctly; I suspect not.

Comment: Always check the return values of functions for errors. And in read/write's cases, also how much data was transferred.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help , it seems you can use the info provided there.

Comment: In `else` part do you want to print only the last character or everything from the file? Depending on this, the `;` after `while` is right or wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You're opening `file` in write-only only mode and yet you're attempting to read from it.  Therefore, your call to `read` will fail and therefore you're not writing anything meaningful to `stdout`.  Depending on how `ch` was initialized, you could be writing exactly nothing.

You need to change `O_WRONLY` to `O_RDONLY`.

Comment: @FriendlyFoe Please don't thank, we know that you appreciate the answer if you mark it as accepted. Additionally, a new but discussed feature is the "Thank you!" marker. -- Please take the [tour] to learn how StackOverflow works.